# Lock iPhone Besides On-Screen Content

Tags: iphone, ios, camera-roll

I am just wondering if iOS devices have the ability to show only on-screen content and lock all other items on the device.

For example: say someone got pulled over and the officer required to see a copy of their insurance document. So they show them a virtual copy of it on their iPhone in the camera roll, but when the officer takes the phone to their car if they try to swipe anywhere on the screen or go to the home screen it requires a faceID/passcode.

Is this a feature that is currently available on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is take a screenshot, save it to your photos and then set it has a lock screen.

- Guided Access is the “official” way to lock one app, but that takes more clicks and your phone isn’t locked when you hand it off.

[image]